# How do I add React component on button click in Data Grid Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I want to open a pop-up-like component 'ViewDownload.js' when I click on the Download Button that is present in a cell in the Data Grid of Material-UI.
Can someone please help me with how I can achieve this?

When I click on the Download button, it should open a new Component on top of the present screen(like a pop-up).

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import ViewDownload from './ViewDownload';

const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'SL. No', width: 70, headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header' },
   
    { field: 'status', headerName: 'PO Status', width: 80, headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header' },
    {
        field: 'action',
        headerName: 'Action',
        type: 'file',
        width: 120,
        headerClassName: 'super-app-theme--header',
        cellClassName: 'super-app-theme--cell',
        renderCell: (params) => (
            <strong>
                <Button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={() => <ViewDownload />}>
                    Download
                </Button>
                {/* {isShown && <ViewDownload />} */}
            </strong>
        )
        // renderCell: renderDetailsButton
    }
];

const rows = [
    {
        id: 1,
        poNo: 'PO_CCTN_0822_001',
        poDate: '01/08/2022',
        from: '08/2022',
        to: '09/2022',
        state: 'TN',
        product: 'MLP',
        certificate: 'Document',
        quantity: '8000',
        status: 'PENDING',
        action: 'View/Download'
    }
];

const Document = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="h2" color="gray">
                Documents
            </Typography>
            <Button variant="contained" sx={{ my: 3, background: 'gray', px: 3, py: 0 }}>
                Filter
            </Button>
            <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center"
                minHeight="100vh"
                flexDirection="column"
                sx={{
                    mt: -18,
                    mx: -14,
                    '& .super-app-theme--header': {
                        backgroundColor: 'gray',
                        color: 'white'
                    },
                    '& .super-app-theme--cell': {
                        color: '#86C029',
                        cursor: 'pointer'
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Box sx={{ height: 300, width: { xs: '60%', sm: '65%', md: '80%' } }}>
                    <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} />
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};

export default Document;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seperate component (Eg: ViewButton.jsx)

```
function ViewButton(){
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return (
       <>
          // button component, onClick = setShow(true)
          { show && (<ViewDownload />)  }
       </>
    )
}
```

Now you can call this component in **renderCell** method

Answer (score 0):

You need create Modal component and ModalButton component.

```
function Modal({ children }) {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, document.body);
}
function ModalButton(props) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button variant="contained" size="small" onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>
        View download
      </button>
      {visible && (
        <Modal>
          <div className="overlay" style={{position: "fixed", inset: "0 0 0 0"}}></div>
          <div 
            style={{
              top:"30%", 
              left: "30%", 
              position: "fixed", 
              width:"300px",
              height: "300px", 
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
            }}
          >
            <div style={{textAlign: "right"}}>
            <button style={{width: "100px"}} onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>Close</button>
            </div>
            <h1>Modal content</h1>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You change `ModalButton` to `Button` in **renderCell**
you can review [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e836hq?file=src/App.js)

Comment: I've done the following things, but now the Button Text is not visible at all, and still, nothing happens when I clicked on it. Can you please show me how to integrate ModalButton in renderCell? I think I'm doing something wrong.